# Difference between -j and -g flag in the open command on macos

Tags: macos, terminal

The open command in macos provides different flags to open our .app application in macOS.
I wanted to know the difference between launching the application using:

1. open -j ( Launches the app hidden)
2. open -g ( Does not bring the application to the foreground)

I have tried multiple application like safari and messages, with both the flags and in both cases the application is launched without the GUI coming up (i.e the GUI is hidden or not visible) but the app icon can be seen launching in the taskbar.

I wanted to know the difference the flags have on the ways our application is launched, because I did not find any.

Also if there is no difference, then why are there two different flags available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically an application on macOS is limited to one running instance. When a file or folder is "opened" or when the `-a` switch is used, the application may be launched or it may already be open and running.

Multiple applications can be open and each application can have multiple windows open. There is a "z-order" to the visible windows of the visible applications. You can make an application the foreground application by clicking one of its windows.

A hidden application will show in the dock but none of its windows will be visible. You can hide an application by secondary clicking (aka right-clicking) on the dock icon and choosing "Hide".

If `TextEdit` is **not** already open and running:

- `open -a TextEdit` will launch TextEdit as visible and bring it to the foreground.
- `open -a TextEdit -j` (or `open -a TextEdit --hide`) will launch TextEdit and TextEdit will be hidden. No TextEdit windows will be visible and the foreground application will not change.
- `open -a TextEdit -g` (or `open -a TextEdit --background`) will launch TextEdit but the foreground application will not change. (i.e. if you use Terminal to run the command, Terminal will remain in the foreground.) If the foreground application is not maximized and not in full screen mode, you will see the TextEdit window(s) in the background.

If `TextEdit` is already open and running:

- `open -a TextEdit` will bring TextEdit to the foreground.
- `open -a TextEdit -j` will bring TextEdit to the foreground. There is no launch and the `-j` effectively does nothing.
- `open -a TextEdit -g` will not change the foreground app. The z-order of application windows is not changed.